# Why do I get this.chats.add is not a function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, this

I am using a module bundler (webpack), since I am using the last version of Firebase and running it with node.js . After running the bundler, i get this error

```
TypeError: this.chats.add is not a function
    at Object.addChat (main.js:2:96471)
    at main.js:2:96498
    at main.js:2:96590
    at main.js:2:96594
```

This is my file (chat.js)

```
class Chatroom {
    constructor(room, username){
        this.room = room;
        this.username = username;
        this.chats = collection(db, 'chats');
    }
    async addChat(message){
        const now = new Date();
        const chat = {
            message,
            username: this.username,
            room: this.room,
            created_at: Timestamp.fromDate(now)
        };
        const response = await this.chats.add(chat);
        return response;
    }
}
 
const chatroom = new Chatroom('gaming', 'shaun');
 
chatroom.addChat('hello everyone')
    .then(() => console.log('chat added'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: What is `collection`?

Comment: Tip: Log `this.chats` to see what it is and check if it has the right methods. The method to add a chat might be named differently (e.g. `addChat`), `collection` might be missing a `return` statement or `collection` might actually be a class, so you should call it like `new collection(db, 'chats')`.